# Pull text from MySql database and split it in paragraph on website

Tags: php, mysql, text, formatting

Can I just insert formated text into database and retrieve it as that? Should formating ( like new line ) appear on website after pulled from database? I have tried it and it seems that is not case.

How to accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: not entirely sure what you're getting at here.  are you trying to insert html into a record in your database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be formatted as is inserted in the database you could output it to a `<pre>` tag to preserve formatting.
If you just want to have the newline replaced by a html tag, you can do that easily:

```
<?php

//be on the safe side, as suggested by Christian Sciberras
$sanitized = htmlspecialchars($databaseContent, ENT_QUOTES);

echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), array("<br />", "<br />"), $sanitized);
```

**Why?**

I use `str_replace()` in this case to show you how it's done. I usually don't replace the new line with a break but with a `</p><p>` (and this is why I didn't go for a `nl2br()` solution)
If you think you'd want paragraphs instead of line breaks, just change the replacement.

Comment: We're talking about text formatting, not best practices to keep yourself clean on XSS :) Of course, that is important too, but I don't think SonOfOmer asked for this

Comment: He asked for output from a database - he should be aware of the consequences, especially when he seems oblivious to the fact that newlines in html are whitespace.

Comment: I will use this solution, looks like it have most control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is method in php that will convert all `\n` to `<br>` so you will have new lines in your html file

```
string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )
```

$is_xhtml menans if your page is XHTML then new lines will be converted to `<br/>` otherwise just `<br>`

I hope this helps